# Get parent widget for Qml application window

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to set the parent of a native `QMessageBox` dialog (or any other custom `QDialog` based class) to a Qml window of type `ApplicationWindow`.

With plain Qt widgets the code looks like this:

```
class MyClass: public QWidget {
void alertMe() {
    QMessageBox::warning(this, ...);
}
};
```

Now I want something like this:

```
class MyClass: public QObject {
Q_INVOKABLE void alertMe() {
    QMessageBox::warning(PARENT, ...);
}
};

//Qml:
ApplicationWindow {
    MyClass {
        id: item
    }
    Button {
        onClicked: item.alertMe()
    }
}
```

One option is to pass a nullptr for PARENT but this centers the alert dialog on the screen and also makes problems on some systems because the dialog is hidden behind other windows. How can I get a PARENT `QWidget` object from the Qml `ApplicationWindow`?

**[Update]**: The scenario is as follows: the main Qml code runs in a `QQuickWidget`. Here I can use the `QQuickWidget` as parent for dialogs. But the problem is that the Qml code can generate new windows (of the type `ApplicationWindow`) and the native dialogs should be parented to these new windows. The easiest way is probably to create separate QQuickWidgets for each window. I do not want to use Qml dialogs due to usability issues.
**[Update end]**

Regards

Comment: You can not, QML has nothing to do with Qt Widgets so you can not do what you want.

Comment: If you are working with QML it is recommended that you use MessageDialog http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html

Comment: **[UPDATE]** do not generate ApplicationWindow for new windows, instead use QQuickWidgets

Comment: So you already know the possibilities, in general it is not good to make a mixture of Qt Widgets with QML widgets since there are limitations in their interaction.